# Django LocaleMiddleware determines the language for me. How do I know what language it determined?

Tags: python, django

I need to know what language it returns, so that I can perform my own actions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from django.utils import translation

def myview(...):
    ...
    lang = translation.get_language()
    ...
```

This will return the language code used in the current thread, so in your case, that set by the middleware.

Answer (score 1):

templates with RequestContext have {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }} by default. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#other-tags